# Froyo Sound Management

Tags: 2.2-froyo, audio, motorola-triumph

I pickup up a Motorola Triumph (running Froyo) for Virgin Mobile a couple weeks ago.  I like the thing, but I just don't understand Android's sound management.  Let me explain:

- Setting SilentMode turns off ringer, but not Media or Alarms.  While this is annoying in and of itself, it also disables the volumn control in the Settings, meaning I can't change the Media volume before something using the Media volume is actually playing!
- Occasionally, the media volume will be waaaaay loud, even though it's only one click away from off.  Furthermore, changing the Ringer volume will then set the Media volumn to a lower level - changing some sort of multiplier, perhaps?  I notice this mostly when using Pandora (it can change volume between songs, and I'll have to go nudge the Ringer volume again to get it to quiet down).

Is there any way to fix these issues?  Make SilentMode silence Media as well as Ringer, AND still allow me to change the Alarm volume?  Or simple make SilentMode ACTUALLY silent?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silent Mode definitely isn't supposed to mute media or alarms.  Both of those are controlled by you, unlike calls and other notifications that are caused by external events.  You wouldn't want to miss your alarm just because you forgot your phone was on silent :) but it's definitely strange that it disables the volume controls entirely, that must be a Motorola thing.

You could try the [Audio Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.smartandroidapps.audiowidget) app for better control over the settings.  It doesn't sync the media volume to the ringer volume, but you can use profiles to quickly set up one where both are muted and then it's easy to switch with a click or two.  It also manages Alarms, Notifications, in-call volume, and "System Volume" (probably the noises you can enable for when you click things and so on).

Comment: I'll give Audio Manager a try, thanks!  Not sure about the motorola thing with the sound controls (from what I understand, the Triumph doesn't have "Motoblur" and uses the stock Android UI, etc).  I agree I wouldn't want my alarms silenced, but having SilentMode mute the Media vol would be helpful.

Comment: @BenCole I can understand why silent mode doesn't disable the Media volume. I quite often plug my phone into speakers or a hifi to play streaming music, etc I do want to hear the music/podcast, etc but don't want it being interrupted all the time as I get new messages, etc.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  AudioManager is an easy-enough-to-use replacement for a full SilentMode.  Unfortunately it still doesn't fix the Pandora problem...it still changes the volumne between songs!  None of the volume sliders (ANYWHERE) have changed though!  I have to go touch the Ringer or Notification sliders in the System Sound settings to get it to quiet down...  I'm still going to accept this answer, because AudioManager is awesome, but I'ma open a new ticket for this Pandora issue.